# SQL extract field issues

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column A which contain 4 fields separated by ‘/’

```
example:  234-12-343/653423/MANAGER/yg@gmail.com
```

Wonder how can i extract field index 2 ? so the final output will be 653423.

(My idea is using regular expression, but have no idea how to do it)

*Database is Oracle 10g

I was able to come out these query. Thanks for the help

```
select substr(ColumnA',
          regexp_instr(ColumnA,'[\/]',1,1,0) + 1,
          regexp_instr(ColumnA,'[\/]',1,2,0) - regexp_instr(ColumnA,1,1,0) - 1  ) 
          as test from dual
```

Comment: This one would be tough just because I don't think there is a function to grab something between two characters. The way you could do it is use substring_index (or a Oracle equivalent because I am talking from a mysql perspective), and take the first part and store it somewhere temporarily, delete it from the actual row and column, and do it once more to get access to it. To solve this problem, the database should be redesigned atomically to separate them already for easy access.

Comment: You can write a function for that by yourself. See here http://info.michael-simons.eu/2007/07/18/simple-tokenizing-with-oracle-plsql/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
substr(column_a, instr(column_a,'/',1,1) + 1, instr(column_a,'/',1,2) - instr(column_a,'/',1,1) - 1)
```

`instr(column_a,'/',1,1)` searches for the first occurance of `/`
`instr(column_a,'/',1,2)` searches for the second occurance of `/`

the `substr` then extracts everything between the two positions

Comment: How could you deal with this if for say the second /` were missing as you would end up with 

    `substr(column_a ,11,0)`

Comment: Found it `substr(column_a,replace(instr(column_a,'/',1,2),'0',length(column_a)))`